# Mule ESB dataweave how to ignore null

Tags: mule, esb, dataweave

In mule ESB dataweave I am having trouble ignoring empty objects, `{}`.
I am trying to check if a particular table exists in my input. If it exists, I do some business logic, if it doesn't exist, it should not be included in the output. However, I am getting `{}` instead of nothing.

**This is my input file :**

```
{
  "srcTable": {
    "srcList": [
      {
        "tableNames": "table1",
        "src": [
          {
            "srcKey": [
              {
                "key": "date",
                "value": "01/01/2016"
              },
              {
                "key": "withinYearTotalMaxSection",
                "value": "2500"
              },
              {
                "key": "previousClaimsTotalMaxSection",
                "value": "25000"
              },
              {
                "key": "previousClaimsTotalMax",
                "value": "50000"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tableNames": "table2",
        "src": [
          {
            "srcKey": [
              {
                "key": "date",
                "value": "01/01/2016"
              },
              {
                "key": "type",
                "value": "A"
              },
              {
                "key": "garden",
                "value": "1000"
              },
              {
                "key": "risk",
                "value": "50000"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "srcKey": [
              {
                "key": "date",
                "value": "01/01/2016"
              },
              {
                "key": "type",
                "value": "B"
              },
              {
                "key": "garden",
                "value": "0"
              },
              {
                "key": "risk",
                "value": "50000"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tableNames": "table3",
        "src": [
          {
            "srcKey": [
              {
                "key": "date",
                "value": "01/01/2016"
              },
              {
                "key": "type",
                "value": "GLD"
              },
              {
                "key": "plants",
                "value": "1500"
              },
              {
                "key": "theft",
                "value": "3000"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "srcKey": [
              {
                "key": "date",
                "value": "01/01/2016"
              },
              {
                "key": "type",
                "value": "SVR"
              },
              {
                "key": "plants",
                "value": "0"
              },
              {
                "key": "theft",
                "value": "1000"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }   
    ]
  }
}
```

**This is my dataweave:**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everything"
---
{ 
  singlevalue: [
    {
      (payload.srcTable.srcList filter ($.tableNames == 'table1') map (r,pos)-> {
        (r.src map {
          ($.srcKey filter ($.key == 'date') map {
            name: 'date',
            value: $.value
          })
        })
      })
    },
    {
      (payload.srcTable.srcList filter ($.tableNames != null and $.tableNames == 'xxx') map (r,pos)-> {
        (r.src map {
          ($.srcKey filter ($.key == 'date') map {
            name: 'date' when $.value != null otherwise null,
            value: $.value
          })
        })
      })
    }
  ]
}
```

**This output file :**

```
{  
  "singlevalue": [
    {
      "name": "date",
      "value": "01/01/2016"
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to get rid of the empty objects, `{}`, please?

Thank you and regards
NK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to remove all the empty elements at the end like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everything"

%var transformation = [
    {
      (payload.srcTable.srcList filter ($.tableNames == 'table1') map (r,pos)-> {
        (r.src map {
          ($.srcKey filter ($.key == 'date') map {
            name: 'date',
            value: $.value
          })
        })
      })
    },
    {
      (payload.srcTable.srcList filter ($.tableNames != null and $.tableNames == 'xxx') map (r,pos)-> {
        (r.src map {
          ($.srcKey filter ($.key == 'date') map {
            name: 'date' when $.value != null otherwise null,
            value: $.value
          })
        })
      })
    }
  ]

%function removeEmptyObjects(e)
  e filter $ != {}
---
{ singleValue: removeEmptyObjects(transformation) }
```

This outputs:

```
{
  "singleValue": [
    {
      "name": "date",
      "value": "01/01/2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, unfortunately both solutions did not work.First solutions compilation error : in this when (sizeOf (payload.srcTable.srcList filter ($.tableNames == 'table1') != 0)      for this i have added extra parenthesis to make it compile, however - i was getting can not coerce number to boolean . and the second solution compiled but still showing the nulls. both solutions did not work. could you please suggest me :) thank you and regards

Comment: Hey Nivi, I went ahead and deleted the first suggestion (I wouldn't recommend it, anyway), and fixed my second. This updated answer should work for you. If it does, please mark as accepted.

Comment: Thank you with little bit of tweak it is working now. Thank you for your help much appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you :) now both of your solutions working :) , thank you for helping me . Bless you, I ve been struggling for last 48hours. God bless you. thank you and regards Nivi

Answer (score 0):

With Josh's help this is the solution if anyone interested.
Using the size Of with the filter combination

```
%dw 1.0
```

### %output application/json skipNullOn="everything"

```
{
singlevalue: [
({
    (payload.srcTable.srcList filter ($.tableNames == 'table1') map (r,pos)-> {
        (r.src map {
            ($.srcKey filter ($.key == 'date') map {
                name: 'date',
                value: $.value
            })
        })
    })
})  when (sizeOf (payload.srcTable.srcList filter $.tableNames == 'table1')) != 0,
({
    (payload.srcTable.srcList filter ($.tableNames != null and $.tableNames == 'xxx') map (r,pos)-> {
        (r.src map {
            ($.srcKey filter ($.key == 'date') map {
                name: 'date' when $.value != null otherwise null,
                value: $.value
            })
        })
    })
}) when (sizeOf (payload.srcTable.srcList filter $.tableNames == 'xxx')) != 0]}
```